# Can Recycle be sacrificed?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can you sacrifice [Recycle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRecycle%5d) to draw cards again if another player has destroyed all lands?

Comment: Recycle tells you to skip your draw phase. When you play a card you can draw a card. Not having lands to be able to play spells suspends the deck from being able to be used. One of the rules of sacrifices is that it can be done if an effect is suspends play.

Comment: Re "*if an effect is suspends play.*", What?

Comment: Why would "if another player has destroyed all lands" have any bearing on sacrificing Recycle; or were you just intending to give a reason why you might want to?

Comment: @GendoIkari They can't make mana, so they can't play spells, so they can't draw cards.

Comment: @Andrew I understand that, but the wording of the question (using "if") seemed to suggest that the user thought the rule would be different under that circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't take an action you weren't instructed to take, so you can't sacrifice an object unless you are instructed to sacrifice it (as a cost, or as an effect).

Whether someone has destroyed all lands or not is irrelevant.

---

By the way, contrary to what you implied, Recycle doesn't prevent cards from being drawn.